# Hide Search results for every thing option in Enterprise search in SP2013

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, search-scope

Hide search options for "Every Thing" in SharePoint Enterprise search in 2013 for all the users.
we tried by removing the Ever thing option but user know the url like pages/results.aspx,
then we can able to see the results,so we want to hide the results for that option.

Regards,
Phani

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? If you want to prevent users from using Search, you can remove the Search Center. I need to understand what you need to do to better answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could additionally delete the results.aspx page - but an advanced user can simple use the api (or the search query tool) to get the results.

Your request sounds more like security by obscurity - please clarify if this answer is not sufficient.